# How can I see console.log output in a node express app when using nginx + passenger

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, passenger

Currently using nginx passenger to serve an express app in production. I can get the error.log and access.log from nginx. But how can I see console.log output that set in the codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All console.log output goes to stderr, which is redirected to the global Nginx error log: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/nginx/log_file/

Comment: Thx. Realized need add passenger_log_level too. One more question, passenger_log_level, passenger_log_file are http level, if the passenger serves multiple servers, is it possible to customize passenger_log_level, passenger_log_file for each servers?

Comment: No, this is not possible. In the future we may allow per-application log files though.

Comment: Searched days in my apache logs... finally found this!